# Causes of diamond shaped gaps PET image

Tags: x-rays, imaging

I'm a math student, and I'm studying about inverse problems in specific reconstruction of PET images, but I have a problem understanding some things. Some sinograms have black diagonal lines, after searching I found that this are called diamond shaped gaps, but I'm not sure what is the source of these lines.
[image] [image]

I believe that the geometry of the scanner causes this, but I can't find this in articles or books. My claim is correct? Does anyone have some reference material? I found references about methods for reconstruction.

Comment: That is the septa which separates the individual scintillator crystals and reduces cross talk to improve spatial resolution.